# Regex for extract the Exception Message fields (Used rsyslog as a message source)

Tags: regex, exception, rsyslog

I'm creating log parser to parse the log message from different source like rsyslog, logback extension, nxlog etc.

I have to extract exception message fields. But I stuck while generating regex for below test string.

**Test String:**

```
2014-10-16 01:32:22,780 ERROR main Sample.main - java.lang.NullPointerException: Sample Log4j Exception
    at Sample.errorLevel3(Sample.java:35)
    at Sample.errorLevel2(Sample.java:31)
    at Sample.errorLevel1(Sample.java:27)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:16)
```

*Note: `\n` and `\t` are received as literal `#012#011` in the string escaped by `rsyslog`*

**Expected Match:**

```
2014-10-16 01:32:22,780
java.lang.NullPointerException
Sample Log4j Exception
----------
Sample.errorLevel3
Sample.java
35
----------
Sample.errorLevel2
Sample.java
31
----------
Sample.errorLevel1
Sample.java
27
```

Comment: In test string "#012#011" used as \r\n. Rsyslog converts new line to the code #012#011

Comment: I found the regex for extracting java stack trace message field
(?:\s+at ([^(]+)\(([^:]+):(\d+))\)

It matches the field :
Sample.errorLevel3
Sample.java
35


Sample.errorLevel2
Sample.java
31


Sample.errorLevel1
Sample.java
27

Comment: #012 , #011 are octal code for char LF and TAB respectively.

Comment: Add `([-\d]+ [\d:,]+)` to the regex from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33565592/5290909). **[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fV9nM8/1)**

Comment: Thanks @Mariano. I used rsyslog as log source. Rsyslog converts newline to octal code #012 #011 (LF, TAB). The actual log message is : 

`2014-10-16 01:32:22,780 ERROR main Sample.main - java.lang.NullPointerException: Sample Log4j Exception#012#011at Sample.errorLevel3(Sample.java:35)#012#011at Sample.errorLevel2(Sample.java:31)#012#011at Sample.errorLevel1(Sample.java:27)#012#011at Sample.main(Sample.java:16)#012`

There are no new line in the log message.

Comment: You can either add the literal `#012#011` in the regex, or [read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5544143/5290909) to disable it

Comment: Thank you @Mariano for your effort.

Now, Its work for me.

Comment: I'm glad it did! In case you decide to keep the escaped characters, here's the [full code](http://ideone.com/pdP4Xi) ... I'm also voting to close this question as duplicate of your previous post, as I think it involves the same criteria.