# PHP error_log ignoring newline

Tags: php, apache, syslog

Running PHP 7.0.1 I have come across a problem, I use `error_log('....'.PHP_EOL.'...');` but when I look at the log file, I get verbatim `\n` in the output.

error_log is set up to use syslog, and ends up in apaches error_log. This is a CentOS 7 system.

Bypassing syslog is not an option as that removes the ability to use syslog forwarding to a central log server.

Comment: Do you insist upon using syslog? If you define a file in php.ini, you can avoid this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203664/php-error-log-and-newline-chars

Comment: syslog forwarding is a facility I care about, so, yes.

Comment: The single comma ' lacks variable interpolation.  You should use double quotes.  Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402566/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-php also see: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: variable interpolation is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Oh, CentOS7 should be using rsyslog instead of plain old syslog.. Perhaps you can configure it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463992/multiline-log-records-in-syslog

Comment: Yes, that is the correct response to this question.

Comment: The duplicate tag at the top points to the wrong answer :/

Comment: @MortenNilsen My original duplicate vote was 50 mins ago, but others just passed it through the queue. For most use cases besides yours, the linked question is probably appropriate (where remote syslog forwarding isn't used). Unfortunately I cannot recast a vote against the other rsyslog/python question which is now more appropriate. I can only vote to lift my original one.

Comment: This also isn't a programming question then - it should have been posted on server fault to a group of sysadmin.  Anytime you receive \n in your text you either haven't interpolated the output or your output was not supported by whatever you outputted to - it's black and white. Server OS doesn't matter in this case or the service handling it when the text comes across raw.

Comment: It can be hard to determine ahead of time where the issue is exactly. In this case, the answer is to either bypass syslog (php answer) or reconfigure syslog (server answer) - so it kind of fits in both camps, does it not?

Answer (score -1):

if you're worried about cross-os compatibility, just use "\r\n". Seems to be the better choice just about every time...

Also remember that \n in single-quotes ( '\n' ) will, indeed, print out the \n verbatim. double-quotes ( "\n" ) will get you what you want.

Comment: The problem here is syslog, which does not support multiline messages.

Comment: Sorry, but that is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski ahhh - i missed that part of it.

Comment: You're welcome, totally missing the question after all..

Comment: eh? are you telling me I misued the downvote? as I understand it, downvoting something is meant to indicate it is an irrelevant or wrong answer..

Comment: are you implying using the standard syslog is not smart? :p

Comment: you know - it took me 4 replies to realize that you're trolling.   removed my replies to you.  enjoy your ... whatever it is you're trying to do.